# Confused about " Duplicate without user-selected canonical"

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

I'm confused about this error in Google console. It's telling me 2 pages are not indexed because of Duplicate without user-selected canonical.
Both are the same page though.  It's the main page of the website.
https://example.com
and
https://example.com/index.html

I've seen several posts about this problem occurring for various reasons.  This is not a complex site though, just a few simple pages of information.  I hope someone can just give me a simple fix.  I have made sure my sitemap only includes https://example.com

Do I add this to my main page...
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/index.html" />`
Or this...
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com" />`
Or is there a better fix?

Just to add something to this... Even though it's telling me the page isn't indexed. I see now that it really is. It appears in google searches. So, I suppose it's a meaningless error. Still not sure I need to use that canonical tag or not. I'm concerned if I use it, google with think my home page is a duplicate of something.

Comment: Which URL is appearing in Google searches?   There are a lot of possibilities: `www` on no `www`, `http` or `https`, with `index.html` or without?  This is eight possible URL variations just based on those three variables.

Comment: Which page does Google say in the canonical URL? If you inspect the affected URLs, Google will tell you which URL they consider to be the "correct" URL for that content.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason Google has found `example.com/index.html` is because

- There is an internal link to it - so change it to `example.com`
- There is an external link - redirect it to `example.com` in `.htaccess`

Or put a canonical tag to point to whichever url you prefer.  I prefer the shorter one.